# I can't suspend ubuntu 20.04

Tags: suspend

Whenever I try to suspend it gives me this error message.

[image: whenever I tried to suspend it gives me this error message]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 0):

Systemctl is a sudo command, try running it with sudo (so: `sudo systemctl [...]` :-)

Comment: What is a "sudo command"?

Comment: @Pilot6, it's a command that can only be run with superuser privileges, hence the name sudo (superuser, do). :-) In Windows terms, it's essentially running smth with administrator/escalated privileges.

Comment: `systemctl` in itself does not always require sudo, but for these types of actions (suspend, reboot etc.), `sudo` is required.